# Can't access google cloud get_http function outside of gcloud CLI

Tags: python, json, http, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm going through the google cloud function HTTP tutorial (Python) and I cannot pass any data to my deployed function outside of using the gcloud CLI. Everything is live, I can see it on my console, but whenever I try to send data to the `hello_http` function with the `content-type`|`application/json` I get a 400 error. I've made sure to set the permissions on my account, but I keep getting the 400 error.

This is the function:

```
# [START functions_helloworld_http]
@functions_framework.http
def hello_http(request):
    """HTTP Cloud Function.
    Args:
        request (flask.Request): The request object.
        <https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#incoming-request-data>
    Returns:
        The response text, or any set of values that can be turned into a
        Response object using `make_response`
        <https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.make_response>.
    """
    request_json = request.get_json(silent=True)
    request_args = request.args

    if request_json and 'name' in request_json:
        name = request_json['name']
    elif request_args and 'name' in request_args:
        name = request_args['name']
    else:
        name = 'World'
    return 'Hello {}!'.format(escape(name))
# [END functions_helloworld_http]
```

And this is the format of my request:

```
curl --request GET 'GOOGLECLOUDURL/hello_http' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{"name":"Keyboard Cat"}'
```

Comment: When you deployed the function, you gave the function a name and matched this to the Python function name try `gcloud functions list --project=${PROJECT}`. You can also `gcloud functions call ${NAME} --project=${PROJECT} --region=${REGION} --data=${DATA}` replacing `${VAR}` with values as appropriate.

Comment: Once you get `gcloud functions call` working, you can append `--log-http` and you'll see the underlying REST call that the command makes.

Comment: It may be (per deleted comment) that you do need to use `POST` instead of `GET` but try the above too.

Answer (score 0):

In order to pass in JSON or any other raw data there needs to be a `-H "Authorization: bearer $(gcloud auth print-identity-token)"` header, with `gcloud auth print-identity-token` being the command run from the gcloud CLI to get the token. Otherwise the server won't accept the input.

Comment: D'oh, my bad. Yes, that'll fix it :-)